# Cloud Function Can't log anything?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've seen all the Question in this topic on StackOverflow but I didn't solve the problem,

so I'm writing a function to send a notification to a specific device I got the FCM token and write them manually in my function as a variable the idea of this function I trigger the real-time DB if I create an order, I will send a simple notify, and log it, But I didn't see anything in Firebase Console "Logs" although the order saved in the DB, So what the problem?

here is my function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// const serviceAccount = require('./service_account.json');
const serviceAccount = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "kapp-42657",
    "private_key_id": ".................",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": ".........",
    "client_id": ".....",
    "auth_uri": "...............",
    "token_uri": "............",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "............": "....."
}

var registrationTokens = "d4QgBGV6HDM:APA91bE77aQBv9XsW5x2arnBYkk9LNZ8jrbn81Al00Z-HFXnJkgWc5dH3AyhWWvPGw7Y2ef4euo9iZPaHUSsviSaFWaQdnOT7XRRDsBzux53gboWkscxIO7DYbOp-wzjQ6Sq1wag3aQj";
// const registrationTokens = AsynStorage.getItem('deviceToken');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://kapp-42657.firebaseio.com"
});

// admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// Notification details.
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Hey Provider One',
        body: `You have Got new notity.`
    }
};

exports.onOrderCreateOrder = functions.database.ref('request/{providerId}/{userId}/order')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const providerId = context.params.providerId;
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        console.log(`New Order from ${userId} to ${providerId}`);
        //New Order from UID to PID
        const orderData = snapshot.val();
        console.log("@orderData", orderData);
        //@orderData { OrderID: { name: 'hey', price: 500, providerService: 'Plumber' } }
        try {
            const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload);
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Try refreshing the Cloud Functions log page in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm already doing it but I didn't see anything

Comment: If the Firebase console isn't working the way you expect, you should reach out to Firebase support for help.  I'm not sure there's much Stack Overflow can do for you.  Log messages for functions should just appear in the console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson sadly, I didn't see anything although I'm using Cloud functions last two month ago and it's worked very well, I submit my problem, thank you

Comment: @DougStevenson my code syntax is right or I'm forgetting anything?