# Send notification to user even when the app is not in the RAM of the device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to send notification to user for any changes in realtime database for firebase in android studio. For my project, I've created a home security app. Which will notify user for any alerts. For example my firebase stores values like:

```
"fire":0,
"smoke":0,
"intruder":0,
"power":0
```

So, what I want is when power is set to 1 and any of the other is set to 1 it will send notification to that user according to the alert.
I am using android studio with java and firebase for the same.
Is there a way to do that. I tried using FCM for the same. But it only send scheduled notification and I can't find a way to send notification when some condition is met

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547676/send-push-notifications-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase

Comment: And this example as well https://medium.com/android-news/cloud-functions-for-firebase-device-to-device-push-notification-f4c548fd9b7d

Comment: You mean like this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes that's what I want. But I can't find a proper resource which I could follow to complete that task

Comment: Since that part of the documentation quite literally describes your use-case, I recommend showing us what you tried based on the documentation and linked resources in there. Without that, it's unlikely we can explain it better than the documentation already does.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).